# Excel Formula - EOMONTH

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

Firstly, my apologies for the post title, i was a little confused what to call it.

I need a formula for calculating payment terms for invoices using this methodology.

Payment Terms are 045,MM. 045,mm mean that it is payable on the 15th day of the following month provided the invoice date +45 is not earlier.. then it will go until the next month.

My Formula for this is IF(DAY(R4+45)<15,EOMONTH(R4,0)+15,EOMONTH(R4,1)+15)
(R4 Represents the invoice date.)

On the sample below you can see that example one is not correct however example two is.

I've tried everything i can think of to get this to work so would appreciate any help.

`Example    Invoice Date    Invoice date + 45  My formula Date  Expected Date
 No.1           01/05/14    15/06/14           15/07/14         15/06/14
 No.2           02/05/14    16/06/14           15/07/14         15/07/14`

Note: the invoice dates could be any day of any given month.

Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE: I completely over thought this problem.

Answer: =IF(I4+45>EOMONTH(I4,0)+15,EOMONTH(I4,1)+15,EOMONTH(I4,0)+15)

Comment: Answer was in there already... just didn't know i should post and answer my own question. Now i do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: =IF(I4+45>EOMONTH(I4,0)+15,EOMONTH(I4,1)+15,EOMONTH(I4,0)+15)